# Regex with fixed Blocks

Tags: .net, regex

I need a regular expression that matches only if the search string is at specific positions. These positions are multiples of 4.

Here is an Example:

Input: `ABCDEABCD123ABCDEFGH`

I would like to match `ABCD`, but only if `ABCD` is at position 0, 4, 8, 12 and so on.

I tried the simple pattern `ABCD`, which matches as follows: **ABCD**E**ABCD**123**ABCD**EFGH.
That is not what I want, the second match should not be found.

As additional requirement: The first match must be at the start of the string. So the following example should not match: "1234EABCD123ABCDEFGH".

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Such a question can't get a satisfactory answer without mentioning the regex engine|tool you use. Please read the description of the regex tag.

Comment: (question edited with right tag as per "I use .Net regex engine." comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>If your regex engine</strike> Since you're using .NET, which supports the [`\G` anchor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#Contiguous), you can use something like this:

```
(?:^|\G)(?:.{4})*?(ABCD)
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/ttIlwW/2).

**Here's a C# sample:**

```
string s = "ABCDEABCD123ABCDEFGH";
string pattern = @"(?:^|\G)(?:.{4})*?(ABCD)";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value + " at " + m.Groups[1].Index.ToString());
}
```

**Output:**

```
ABCD at 0
ABCD at 12
```

**Note:** As @Wiktor [pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058370/regex-with-fixed-blocks#comment91069263_52058524), `(?:^|\G)` is only required if you want to support multiple lines like what's shown in the regex101 example *(as opposed to treating them as a single line)*. And in this case, you would need to pass `RegexOptions.Multiline` as a third argument to the `Regex.Matches()` method.

Comment: I use .Net regex engine, and it matches only the first ABCD.

Comment: @AndreasGey My bad, I made a mistake. Updated the answer and added a C# sample.

Comment: `(?:^|\G)` only makes sense when using `RegexOptions.Multiline` option. `\G` will suffice in the real code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I intended to make it match multiple lines indeed. I just forgot to reflect that in the C# code. Or perhaps I didn't use `RegexOptions.Multiline` because the example uses only one line. It's a good point though :)

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed: That regex looks nice. But i have one problem: I use the Property Index from the Match-Object, and the second match has the index 4, while m.Groups[1].Index is 12. Is it possible to build an regex where Match.Index for the second match is 12?

Comment: @AndreasGey Why is that important? Can't you just use the group's index instead? Anyways, yes it's possible. You can do something like this, for example: [`(?<=^|(?:^|\G)(?:.{4})+?)ABCD`](http://rextester.com/FGD96512).

Comment: Thank you Ahmed Abdelhameed. I have an additional requirement, the first match must be at the start of the string. How can this be achieved?

Comment: @AndreasGey Please don't keep changing the requirements because that makes the question too broad. If you have another question, you can ask a _new_ one. That being said, you can either replace the original regex with [`(?:^|\G(?:.{4})*?)(ABCD)`](https://regex101.com/r/ttIlwW/3) or replace the last one with [`(?<=^|\G(?:.{4})*?)ABCD`](http://rextester.com/ZTAZ91005).

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex as a pattern manipulation tool, not a token parser. It is up to a following process to *implement the business logic* and take the results to provide an answer.

```
var text      = "ABCDEABCD123ABCDEFGH"; 
var locations = new List<int> { 0, 4, 8, 12 };

Regex.Matches(text, "ABCD")
     .OfType<Match>()
     .Where (mt => locations.Contains(mt.Index))
     .Select (mt => mt.Index)
     .ToList();
```

// Result is `{ 0, 12 }`

Comment: Nice answer, but it's propably better to get rid of the `locations` list and replace the `Where` statement with `.Where(mt => mt.Index % 4 == 0)`.

Comment: I thought of the `%`, but the OP seems to have an issue with certain locations and this will allow the OP to adjust as needed w/o worrying about jiggering the regex pattern.